# Custom select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have requirement to use custom dropdown menu.
I have searched a lot for a custom combobox implementation but I didn't find one that matches my requirements, namely:
I need up/down arrows on the side of the combobox. When the user clicks one of them, the value changes, but not list should be displayed.

The graphic design is similar to this one: http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

Comment: Sometimes ago I saw that kind of plugin. so I dont want to make my own I just want use plugin for that. I have search over internet around 2 hours but cant find it. If you could tell me the name of that kind of select box

Comment: This is not a please for others to do your research for you.  Perhaps just take one of the ones you found and modify.  You should ask questions on here when you run into specific problems in implementing.

Comment: I think you should implement this functionnality by extending a plugin like DropKick... Unless you remember the one you saw sometimes ago.

Comment: It will take long time if I customize it, that why I need to find that plugin

Comment: You are looking for a spinner, not a custom select. Here is an example (the page selector) http://demo.akweb.it/akgrid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the following

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/541/jQuery-UI-Spinner-numeric-stepper

http://www.egrappler.com/contents/smartspin/demo/spinner.htm

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138077/Spinner